# React dropdown menu component

Tags: reactjs

I have bumped into [this article](https://engineering.tripping.com/building-an-recursive-nested-dropdown-component-in-react-b1c883e06ac4) the other day but struggled to make a usable demo on codepen. I want to use this component to make two-level dropdown menu button but I keep getting syntax error at line 5.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mikeychang2/e7c8201b2bee686e448706c35dd5e08f#file-nesteddropdown-jsx) is the component. Note that I am just starting my journey with React.js

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly getting this error -

> **'const' can only be used in a .ts file.**

That is because const is inside the class.

Move it outside and it will work fine.